# How to graph binary clustered data in R using a two-dimensional histogram/frequency chart

Tags: r, graph, cluster-analysis

I am using R to graph clustered binary data. The data looks like this:
[Table of data.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwe8W.png)
My goal is to graph the data in the following way:
[image: Adding the Cluster graph.]

I tried to use fviz_cluster, but I was not able to make R understand, that there are actually only two dimensions to the graph (A; B) and that these two dimensions each have three subcategories (A_1, A_2, A_3; B_1, B_2, B3).
Thanks a lot for any helpful suggestions!

Comment: hi wtgw, try not to paste images. It would help us and help you if you can post examples of your data and the code you have tried.

Comment: Also. Your coding for A looks like a set of indicator variables (e.g. red=A1, blue=A2, green=A3) since each row has a value of 1 on only one column. But B is different. rows have 1s on 2 or even all 3 categories. Your data has more than 2 dimensions.

Comment: I don't know if "cluster" is the right terminology to use here. IMHO you'll only find all the "wrong" tools if you search for this term. That is probably why fviz_cluster does not work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to apply a "tree classifier" such as J48 (aka C45), and then visualize the decision boundary.

In Weka it would look like this:

[image]

Here I have used the Iris dataset and then chosen 2 numeric attributes for x and y coordinates. In my case  there is an  attribute "class" (= the flower name) that can be predicted from the leaf-width, and is color-coded here. I am not sure if you have such an attribute in your dataset.

If you don't: your dataset reminds me of a  discrete optimization problem (knapsack problem) that I cannot solve here.